# DVD-RW disc mounts as DVD-R in every disk drive I use

Tags: dvd, disc

I have a few blank DVD-RW discs, though old, worked normally until recently. Every drive I insert them in, recognizes them as DVD-R discs, and once I write to them, they become read-only. I have tried multiple computers, even a Mac, and they all claim that my disc is a DVD-R and will only write once. I can't even blank or format them, they all say it has write protection on the discs, even when they haven't been written to ever before. I don't think it's disc rot, since the discs weren't exposed to light for more than a few seconds at a time before I began using them again. The discs have also previously written and formatted normally, but now do not anymore. What do I do to fix these discs? They're branded Memorex, if that helps.

Comment: Likely you've finalized the DVD. You *might* be able to un-finalize; see https://www.avforums.com/threads/can-you-un-finalize-dvd-rw.483030/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't think that is the case, since even some disks that I have never written to will not format, returning the same write protection errors.